# Page Login access tokens

Tags: facebook-graph-api, hash, access-token

I have been using the api and in the past the call to get a list of pages would return a page access_token string with pipes (|). Just like this image: 
http://developers.facebook.com/attachment/page_tokens.png

Now after upgrading to the new sdk it is returned like this:

`AAAD4IFCrso0BAIIaDhBIfadsavdasifIjTleB9Fu92pAYzfBbYXIxdzm9cFZBgZBrNjI0KSKOqCzw2kQCzu1hra2owH4fX5youiNtRrBzlweM3aZDZD
// Not a real token`

The problem is now I can't seem to publish events to pages. All sites I have that are setup with the old access_token works fine.

Does anybody if this is a change that hasn't been talked about or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of the OAuth 2.0 and HTTPS migration that has been mentioned many times on the [Facebook developer blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog) and [Facebook Roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/oauth2-https-migration/).  All access_tokens will be sent encrypted (no pipes).  They will and do work like normal tokens, unless you were doing some kind of parsing of the tokens which is no longer possible.